# jQuery DataTables listing with JSON data

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datatable, jquery-plugins, datatables

```html
$.ajax({
        url: "https://localhost:450/rest/products?pageNumber=1&pageCount=100",
        type:"post",
        dataType:"json",
        traditional:true,
        contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        processData : false,
        data:
            JSON.stringify(hostAddresses)

        ,



       success:function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            var trHTML ='';
           $('.js-exportable').DataTable({
               dom: 'Bfrtip',
               responsive: true,
               buttons: [
                   'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
               ]
           });
            for(var i = 0 ; i < response.length ; i++)
            {

                for(var j = 0 ; j < response[i].Products.length ; j ++)
                {


                   // trHTML  += '<tr><td>' +response[i].IP + '</td><td>' + response[i].Products[j].Product + '</td><td>' + response[i].Products[j].CVECount + '</td>';
                    //console.log(response[i].Products[j].Product);
                    //console.log(trHTML);
                    //$('#ProductsTableBody').append(trHTML);
                }

            }


        },
        error:function (xhr) {
            console.log("Error...");

        }
    })
```

I have this code. The code in the comment lines is the process of adding to the regular-ordered list. But not work for jQuery dataTables. How can I do this.

Secondly, after adding these dataTable how can I assign id to list items so that it directs special page associated with that list item when clicked.

Comment: You'd be far better using DataTables to generate the table for you. Take a look here: https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax

Comment: I have checked that but i couldnt find a solution

Comment: Perhaps if you provided a sample of the data you get back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you are initializing DataTables before populating the table. Hence it can only process a empty table.

You need to move the `DataTable` initializer after the `for` loop:

```
    success:function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        var trHTML ='';

        for(var i = 0 ; i < response.length ; i++)
        {

            for(var j = 0 ; j < response[i].Products.length ; j ++)
            {


                trHTML  += '<tr><td>' +response[i].IP + '</td><td>' + response[i].Products[j].Product + '</td><td>' + response[i].Products[j].CVECount + '</td>';
                console.log(response[i].Products[j].Product);
                console.log(trHTML);
                $('#ProductsTableBody').append(trHTML);
            }

        }
        $('.js-exportable').DataTable({
           dom: 'Bfrtip',
           responsive: true,
           buttons: [
               'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
           ]
       });

    },
```